# Fluent NHibernate 3 and Oracle.DataAccess

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, odp.net, fluent

my question:

I am trying to use `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` Provider with NHibernate (Fluent), and I configured it as follows:

```
Fluently.Configure().Database(OracleClientConfiguration.Oracle10.Provider("Oracle.DataAccess.Client").ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("ORACLE1"))).
```

and I have this error:

```
"Could not load type Oracle.DataAccess.Client. Possible cause: no assembly name specified.":"
```

I already add Reference to `Oracle.Dataaccess` dll (ODAC) with copy local = true, but error persist...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a working code snippet:

```
public static void InitializeNHibernate()
{
    var configurer = (OracleClientConfiguration.Oracle10.ShowSql().ConnectionString(c =>
                 c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("development"))
                 .DefaultSchema("myschema")
                 .UseReflectionOptimizer()
                 .Cache(c =>
                         c.ProviderClass<SysCacheProvider>()
                         .UseQueryCache()));

    var cfg = Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(configurer)
        .Mappings(m =>
                      {
                          m.FluentMappings
                              .AddFromAssemblyOf<Employee>()
                              .Conventions.Add<OracleDateTimeTypeConvention>();

                          m.HbmMappings
                              .AddFromAssemblyOf<Employee>();
                      })
        .ExposeConfiguration(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.SetProperty(Environment.Hbm2ddlKeyWords, "auto-quote");
            configuration.SetProperty(Environment.GenerateStatistics, "true");
            configuration.SetProperty(Environment.CurrentSessionContextClass, "web");
            configuration.SetProperty(Environment.CommandTimeout, "60");
        });
}
```

Without specifying a provider, it automatically picks Oracle DataAccess up.

**Edit:**
It does **not** pick it up automatically, I just have it on my connection string:

```
<add name="development" connectionString="Data Source=XXX;User ID=yyy;Password=zzz;" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"/>
```

Comment: Are You sure it uses Oracle DataAccess?? isnt it using System.Data.OracleClient?

Comment: I'm sure.If I remove the reference, It'll ask specifically for it. Fyi, you don't need System.Data.OracleClient as a reference.

Comment: i tryied too providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" in connection string, but it seems be ignored.

Comment: How did you put the Oracle.DataAccess.Client on your box? XCOPY or install, since ADO.NET providers must be referenced in config files (see machine.config for example of SQL Server provider).

Comment: Installed it. It didn't show up on my <add reference> options, so I added it manually.

Comment: I added this in my .csproj by hand: <Reference Include="Oracle.DataAccess, Version=10.2.0.100, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />

Comment: The documentation (as of now anyway) for Provider() says "This shouldn't be necessary if you're using one of the provided database configurations" - which I'm interpreting to mean (having not tested anything yet) - I don't need any more than this? - Fluently.Configure().Database(OracleClientConfiguration.Oracle10.ConnectionString(connectionString)) - I just wanted to confirm the edit you made is still correct.